# How to check input location with accuracy inside in polygon on map or not?

Tags: xcode, swift3, location, mkmapview, floating-accuracy

I have plotted polygon on a map using MkMapView successfully. Now I want to check user location inside this polygon with accuracy. suppose I have latitude = 50.840473 and longitude = -0.146755 and accuracy = 60 then, for a location situated 30 meters outside of the plotted polygon on the map .

How can I calculate this distance = 30-meter using Latitude, longitude, Accuracy . because without using accuracy I have successfully check user location inside the polygon or not. using below code.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
{
    if overlay is MKPolygon {
        let polygonRenderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polygonRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        polygonRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        polygonRenderer.lineWidth = 3


        let currentMapPoint: MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.840473, -0.146755))

        let polygonViewPoint: CGPoint = polygonRenderer.point(for: currentMapPoint)


       if polygonRenderer.path.contains(polygonViewPoint)
       {
            print("Your location was inside your polygon.")
        }
        return polygonRenderer
    }

    return MKOverlayPathRenderer()
}
```

using this code I have been checked successfully input lat long location inside the polygon. But how to use accuracy parameter to check how much distance between input location and plotted polygon.